# bash: ((: ave=total/numLines : division by 0 ( error token is "numLines ")

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

I'm writing a bash script and I get this error:

```
bash:  ((: ave=total/numLines : division by 0 (error token is "numLines ")
```

And this is my code:

```
total="$( cut -d '|' -f ${array[$index]} folder/${files[$x]} | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' )"

numLines="$( cut -d '|' -f ${array[$index]} folder/${files[$x]} | awk 'NF' | wc -l )"

(( ave=total/numLines ))
```

The value of variable 'ave' could be calculated and printed correctly, but I keep getting the 'division by 0' error. I tried to assign a value to 'numLines' at the beginning but doesn't seem to work.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: And when you insert `echo ${numLines}` just before the divison, what do you see? My guess is that it will be zero :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  No that just gives the correct number of lines :(

Comment: Why don't you just count the lines in your first AWK command at the same time you're summing the first field and calculate the average in an `END` clause?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I'm new so not sure how to do this as I need to remove a few empty lines at the end while counting..

Comment: Can you run the script with `set -x` and post the resulting debug log?

Comment: Use a clause `NF { sum += $1; count++ }` to only count non-empty lines. Then use `END { print sum/count }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Barmar's and my comments:

AWK can extract fields with different delimiters (no need for `cut`):

```
read -r total ave <<< "$(awk -F '|' -v field=${array[$index]} 'NF { sum += $field; count++ } END {print sum, sum/count}' "folder/${files[$x]}")"
```

Note that in `sum += $field`, the dollar sign causes the field number held in the variable `field` to refer  to the contents of that field. (It's not a variable designation such as that used in Bash.) The `-v` argument is the way to pass a Bash variable into AWK as an AWK variable. The pattern used here (`NF`) matches all non-empty lines and the action is enclosed with `{}`. The `END` pattern is special and is executed when all input has been consumed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I found my prob was on files not commands… But AWK is definitely more reliable and quicker than my method so I changed mine. Will keep on learning :o)